# How to add two different effects to SwiperJS?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I want to set "fade" as a transition effect for auto play transitions and "Slide" for the transition when swiping manually or using navigation buttons.
Is this possible ? How can achieve it ?

Comment: No way (True to July 20). Swiper doesn't support this idea. 
https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/issues/1418

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in setting
effect: "fade",
speed:20,

```
  loop: true,
  fadeEffect: { crossFade: true },
  slidesPerView: 1,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  },
```